# What is this bash shortcut?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I was watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiRt3mY7Rrw) and at 3m03s the guy went immediately from a blank bash line to this (vlc screenshot with the exact frame):

[image]

, with cursor just after the "t" letter, ready to type the rest and enter it.
I could definitely make use of this shortcut, any idead how he did this ?

Once I get the answer and know what it is, I will rephrase this vague title accordingly so people can find this question.

Comment: He could just page up and moved the cursor, the video could have been cut to speed up.

Comment: @KamilCuk it seems to me it was a live video, and the the "systemctl st[cursor]monit" happened instantly, I downloaded the video and went frame-by-frame to investigate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: No need to download the video. Stop video with spacebar and then press `.` for next frame and `,` for previous frame.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it's the TAB, or the TAB TAB shortcut (press the TAB two times, and you get a list). This goes into the directory you're currently in, and expands to the filenames.

Comment: doesn't quite seem like it

Comment: Ah, I just watched the video: he had copied that command from somewhere, and most probably used the right-click of the mouse to paste it in the terminal.

Comment: if that was the case why would the cursor instantly be after "st" and not at the end of the line ?

Comment: No, it puts the content of the clipboard and puts the cursor immediately after it, not at the end of the line.